# Is specifically indicating "uncontrolled airfield, student handling radios" by writing "uncontrolled" in a student's log book necessary?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training

I'm a student pilot with 52 flight hours.  I've had multiple lessons at the same uncontrolled airfield handling the communications on each leg while doing touch and goes.  The last lesson my instructor wrote "uncontrolled" in my log book.  I spoke with the chief flight instructor she said that it was to indicate that I was flying in an uncontrolled airfield and handling all the radios.  Is it necessary to reflect radio communications for the private pilot exam with the DPE?
As I indicated above all my flight training for touch and goes (except one) has been at one uncontrolled airfield.  After the first lesson on calling postions in the pattern I've handled all radio communications.  Is writing "uncontrolled" necessary for logging progress?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add a tag to indicate which jurisdiction you are asking about (e.g. *faa-regulations* for the US)?

Comment: Hi ubah, and welcome to Aviation Stack Exchange. I agree with Bianfable above that this question needs to specify a jurisdiction (though your mention of DPE makes me think you may be looking for answers for the US; either way, it's better to spell it out). I also edited the title of your question to try to better summarize what you are asking. If you feel my edit changed your intent in any way, by all means feel free to [Edit] further.

Comment: If you haven't spent any time at a controlled field, I'd ask your instructor to do your next set of T&G's at a controlled field. Try to get some variety, Class C and D. Getting into the controlled airspace and into the field can be intimidating if you've never done it before. Don't do it for the first time with your DPE.

Comment: I think the concept of "it's your (log)book, write in it whatever you want to" sort of applies.  Things that NEED to be recorded to prove currency & requirements accomplished, need to be there.  Stuff you WANT recorded, as a memory jogger or to reminisce later, can be there.  Extraneous stuff isn't really a harm, but if it doesn't reflect requirements met, it doesn't have to be there. Noting experience at both controlled + uncontrolled airports could be nice to have, tho looking up the airport can do that too (unless it closes or changes status).

Comment: @RalphJ Even if the airport closes or changes status, surely historical records could be referenced to determine its status at the time? After all, some airports switch between controlled and uncontrolled based on time of day or day of week, so even absent that, it's not as simple as being one or the other...

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that the requirements of training are met.

For a private pilot under the FAA system, you need to have completed three solo landings at a controlled airport.  Otherwise, radio communication is a required line-item for training.  You should always log the airport of departure and arrival as well as the date.  If someone wants to know whether it was controlled or uncontrolled, they could look up the airport and see if it had a tower on that date, but they shouldn't need to since ***the required solo with an operating control tower should be specified in your training remarks***.

Any examiner in the area would likely know whether any given airport is controlled or not simply from memory, being familiar with the area you're in. The examiner must check to make sure you meet the minimum requirements for the certificate or rating.

Beyond the three landings with a tower and the required standard communications training, there is no need to specify controlled vs. uncontrolled airport operations.

Comment: Thank you for all the help.  I updated for faa-regulations.  The flight school is within class c airspace with a control tower.  I do the t/g's at an uncontrolled airport.  This is just the first time he wrote uncontrolled in my log book and I was advised that it indicated uncontrolled airport and I was doing all the communications in the pattern.

Comment: @ubah Yes, you *may* write anything you would like to.  You don't need to specify controlled or uncontrolled other than to meet the requirements of 14 CFR 61.109(a)(5)(iii).